# How to add rows to a intermediary table in using EF core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

As most of you who are here to answer are probably aware, EF core doesn't implement many-to-many relationships.  There's a common work around, which is creating an intermediary table (join table), and defining a one-to-many relationship between each model that you want to be included in the many-to-many relationship, and the intermediary one.  The conventional structure looks like this (using my personal classes):

```
class Deck
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DeckCard> DeckCards {get; set;}
}

class Card
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DeckCard> DeckCards {get; set;}
}

class DeckCards
{
    public int DeckID {get; set;}
    public Deck Deck {get; set;}
    public int CardID {get; set;}
    public Card Card {get; set;}
}
```

My interface is fairly simple.  Relative code directly below.

**ViewModel**

```
class DeckVm
{
    public Deck Deck {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Card> Cards {get; set;}
}
```

**View**

```
@model TheMorningStar.ViewModels.DeckVm

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Build Your Deck";
}

<h2><strong>Build Your Deck</strong></h2>

@foreach (var item in Model.Cards)
{
    <img id="@item.ID;@item.Name" class="card" style="width:175px;height:250px;" src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" />
}


<form name="builder"  asp-controller="Decks" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Deck</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input name="Deck.Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input name="Deck.Class" value="@ViewBag.ClassChoice" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input name="Deck.DeckCards" hidden />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/AddCardCreateView.js"></script>
```

**AddCardCreateView (JS file; see last line of View file)**

```
//<img> elements derived from Model.Cards are of type: 'card'
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

//Holds card id's and represents the deck.
var deckList = []; 

//For each element in the cards array: define event listener
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        //this.id references the id of generated <img> elements in the Decks.Create view.
        var cardInfo = this.id.split(';');
        var cardId = cardInfo[0];
        var cardName = cardInfo[1];
        //cardCount is used to determine how many times a card id is found in the deckList array
        var cardCount = 0;

        //check the decklist for matching card id and increment cardCount
        for (var x = 0; x < deckList.length; x++) {
            if (deckList[x] === cardId) {
                cardCount++;
            }
        }

        if (cardCount < 3 && deckList.length < 30) {
            deckList.push(cardId);

        }
    });
}
```

I'm guessing that I'll have to do some magic in the JS file to prep the data for the Deck.DeckCard form input element in the View page.  Can anyone lead me in the right direction here?

Comment: Your code makes little sense. You create a new `Deck()` class and assign it's ID to `DeckCard`? How is that supposed to work, your `ID` will always have its default value 0, which is not a valid value of a entity. You will first have to persist your `Deck` to the database. Or better you use the navigation property, then EF will do the relations for you

Comment: Try to untangle transport and persistence concerns. It shouldn't matter from which source you receive data that should be inserted. Your `Create` method shouldn't have this `JSONDeckList` argument. I suggest you first write a unit test (or integration test) for this `Create` method, without any reference to MVC, JSON or whatever UI/transport implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using IDs in your code but since `Deck` isn't persisted, there is no ID (it will have its default value, 0 for int for example).

Try using the navigation properties instead.

```
Create(string Class, string Name, string JSONDeckList)
{
    var deck = new Deck();

    deck.Class = Class; deck.Name = Name;

    // cards should be a IEnumerable<Card>
    foreach (var card in cards) {
        deck.DeckCards.Add(new DeckCard { Deck = deck, Card = card });
    }
}
```